# R - Moving misplaced values in correct column

Tags: r, dataframe

Beginner here, I have a large dataframe with multiple columns in which some values are misplaced but at least have the right column name in front of the value. Imagine a dataframe like this:

```
Country <- c("Spain", "Time:16 Mar 2018 - 23 Apr 2018", "USA")
Platform <- c("Twitter", "Country:Germany", "Cap:200")
Start_Time <- c("10 Jun 2018 - 2 Jul 2018", "Platform:Facebook", "Platform:Instagram")
Cap <- c("300", "500", "Time:10 Jun 2018 - 2 Jul 2018")

dat <- data.frame(Country, Platform, Start_Time, Cap)
```

```
Output:
Country                          Platform          Start_Time                       Cap

Spain                            Twitter           10 Jun 2018 - 2 Jul 2018         300
Time:16 Mar 2018 - 23 Apr 2018   Country:Germany   Platform:Facebook                500
USA                              Cap:200           Platform:Instagram               Time:10 Jun 2018 - 2 Jul 2018
```

As you can see, if the values are misplaced, the correct column name (or at least an indication like with Start_Time and Time:) is set in front of the value.

How can I switch the values into their respective columns? My original dataframe has 729 rows and 45 columns, so the less manual work, the better. The correct output should look like this:

```
Output:
Country    Platform          Start_Time                       Cap

Spain      Twitter           10 Jun 2018 - 2 Jul 2018         300
Germany    Facebook          16 Mar 2018 - 23 Apr 2018        500
USA        Instagram         10 Jun 2018 - 2 Jul 2018         200
```

Thank you very much.

EDIT: Here is the output of dput(df_short_head) which is the first 6 rows of my original dataframe

```
structure(list(Presale_Time = c("16 Apr 2018  -  30 Apr 2018                            ", 
"Whitelist/KYC:Whitelist + KYC", "Country:Jersey", "ICO Time:26 Mar 2018  -  23 Apr 2018                            ", 
"", "ICO Time:01 Mar 2018  -  31 Mar 2018                            "
), ICO_Time = c("01 May 2018  -  20 July 2018                            ", 
"Country:Singapore", "", "Country:UK", "", "Country:Malaysia"
), Whitelist_KYC = c("\nWhitelist/KYC:\nWhitelist + KYC\n", "", 
"", "", "", ""), Country = c("Spain", "", "", "", "", ""), Platform = c("Ethereum                                                            ", 
"Ethereum                                                            ", 
"Ethereum                                                            ", 
"Scrypt                                                            ", 
"Total supply:1,087,156,610.00 FXT", "Ethereum                                                            "
), Token_Type = c("ERC20", "ERC20", "ERC20", "Scrypt", "", "ERC20"
), Available_for_sale = c("1,008,000,000 CST", "2,200,000,000 ZPR", 
"200,000,000 GNY", "20,000,000 SHARD", "", "Total supply:15,000,000,000.00 SRCOIN"
), Total_Supply_2 = c("1,124,463,121.00 CST", "1,850,000,000.00 ZPR", 
"400,000,000.00 GNY", "25,391,088.27 SHARD", "", ""), ICO_Price = c(" 0.05 USD", 
" 0.0375 USD", "Accepting:BTC, ETH, LSK, ASCH", " 0.57 USD", 
"Accepting:ETH, BTC", " 0.006 USD"), Accepting = c("ETH, BTC, Fiat", 
"ETH", "Soft cap:1,000,000 USD", "BTC, ETH, LTC, XRP", "Hard cap:40,000 ETH", 
"ETH"), Soft_Cap = c("983,733 EUR", "5 000 ETH", "Hard cap:400,000,000 GNY", 
"1,500 ETH", "", ""), Hard_Cap = c("71,400,000 EUR", "48 000 ETH", 
"Bonuses:20% sale for first 100,000,000 tokens", "12,500 ETH", 
"", "")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I do not know if you are familiarized with tidyverse and dplyr functions, so I used classic functions in my solution (taking into account the last update with the complete format). It is important to notice that some values started with "Bonuses:", but you did not define this column, so it was not considered in the code.

```
dat <- structure(list(Presale_Time = c("16 Apr 2018  -  30 Apr 2018                            ", 
                                       "Whitelist/KYC:Whitelist + KYC", "Country:Jersey", "ICO Time:26 Mar 2018  -  23 Apr 2018                            ", 
                                       "", "ICO Time:01 Mar 2018  -  31 Mar 2018                            "), 
                      ICO_Time = c("01 May 2018  -  20 July 2018                            ",
                                   "Country:Singapore", "", "Country:UK", "", "Country:Malaysia"), 
                      Whitelist_KYC = c("\nWhitelist/KYC:\nWhitelist + KYC\n", "",
                                        "", "", "", ""), 
                      Country = c("Spain", "", "", "", "", ""), 
                      Platform = c("Ethereum                                                            ",
                                   "Ethereum                                                            ",
                                   "Ethereum                                                            ",
                                   "Scrypt                                                            ",
                                   "Total supply:1,087,156,610.00 FXT", "Ethereum                                                            "), 
                      Token_Type = c("ERC20", "ERC20", "ERC20", "Scrypt", "", "ERC20"), 
                      Available_for_sale = c("1,008,000,000 CST", "2,200,000,000 ZPR",
                                             "200,000,000 GNY", "20,000,000 SHARD", "", 
                                             "Total supply:15,000,000,000.00 SRCOIN"), 
                      Total_Supply = c("1,124,463,121.00 CST", "1,850,000,000.00 ZPR",
                                         "400,000,000.00 GNY", "25,391,088.27 SHARD", "", ""), 
                      ICO_Price = c(" 0.05 USD",
                                    " 0.0375 USD", "Accepting:BTC, ETH, LSK, ASCH", " 0.57 USD",
                                    "Accepting:ETH, BTC", " 0.006 USD"), 
                      Accepting = c("ETH, BTC, Fiat",
                                    "ETH", "Soft cap:1,000,000 USD", "BTC, ETH, LTC, XRP", 
                                    "Hard cap:40,000 ETH",
                                    "ETH"), 
                      Soft_Cap = c("983,733 EUR", "5 000 ETH", "Hard cap:400,000,000 GNY",
                                   "1,500 ETH", "", ""), 
                      Hard_Cap = c("71,400,000 EUR", "48 000 ETH",
                                   "Bonuses:20% sale for first 100,000,000 tokens", "12,500 ETH", 
                                   "", "")), 
                 row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

# Define a vector with (columns') categories
groupNames <- gsub(x = colnames(dat), pattern = "_", replacement = " ")

# Define a function for correcting missplacing
correcting <- function(x, groupNames){
  
  # Coerce input vector as character
  x <- gsub(x = as.character(x), pattern = "\n", replacement = "")
  x <- gsub(x = x, pattern = "/", replacement = " ")
  
  # Find the missplaced positions
  index <- do.call(c, sapply(groupNames, grep, x = x, ignore.case = TRUE))
  
  # If there is any missplaced value...
  if(length(index) > 0){
    
    oldValues <- x[index]
    
    x[index] <- NA
    
    # Correct misplacing and remove text used as clue
    x[match(names(index), groupNames)] <- gsub(x = oldValues, 
                                               pattern = "^[[:print:]]{1,}:", 
                                               replacement = "")
    
  }
  
  return(x)
}

# Apply function by row, transposing and coerce output as data frame
out <- as.data.frame(t(apply(dat, 1, correcting, groupNames = groupNames)))

# Replace names of columns
colnames(out) <- colnames(dat)
```

Comment: Thanks @Wencheng Lau-Medrano, on my original dataframe this seems to have worked only on the country column, but not on the rest - any idea why? Will add screenshot of my output in the question above as an edit

Comment: @Soph2010 That is because my code was designed for the (reproducible) example that you indicated before. In your screenshot, I see that you have more columns, so you could have to modify my code in order to adapt it to your specific case. I could do that, but I would require you share the data frame in the complete format (just with some rows, those ones with problems).

Comment: Sure @Wencheng Lau-Medrano, I just posted dput(df_short) of the first 6 rows, does that help?

Comment: @Soph2010 OK, I have posted the new code, but check the observation about some not defined columns.

Comment: @Soph2010 Besides, it is important to notice that I changed the name of one column: from Total_Supply_2 to Total_Supply in order to facilitates the finding of starting labels for this case.

Comment: Thank you @Wencheng Lau-Medrano, seems to be working great!!

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Supplied sample data
Country <- c("Spain", "Time:16 Mar 2018 - 23 Apr 2018", "USA")
Platform <- c("Twitter", "Country:Germany", "Cap:200")
Start_Time <- c("10 Jun 2018 - 2 Jul 2018", "Platform:Facebook", "Platform:Instagram")
Cap <- c("300", "500", "Time:10 Jun 2018 - 2 Jul 2018")

dat <- data.frame(Country, Platform, Start_Time, Cap) 

# Code
dat2 <- dat |> 
  pivot_longer(everything()) |> 
  separate(value, into = c("name2", "value"), sep = ":") |> 
  mutate(name = if_else(!is.na(value), name2, name),
         value = if_else(is.na(value), name2, value),
         name = if_else(str_detect(name, "Time"), "Start_Time", name)) |> 
  select(-name2) |> 
  mutate(group = rep(1:nrow(dat), each = 4)) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "name", values_from = "value")

dat2
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   group Country Platform  Start_Time                Cap  
#>   <int> <chr>   <chr>     <chr>                     <chr>
#> 1     1 Spain   Twitter   10 Jun 2018 - 2 Jul 2018  300  
#> 2     2 Germany Facebook  16 Mar 2018 - 23 Apr 2018 500  
#> 3     3 USA     Instagram 10 Jun 2018 - 2 Jul 2018  200
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Carl, however when I run the code with my original dataframe I get the error ```Error in mutate(select(mutate(separate(pivot_longer(df_short, everything()), : 

✖ `group` must be size 8748 or 1, not 2916.``` and 2 warnings: ```Warning: Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 2 rows [492, 6216].``` and ```Warning: Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 6731 rows [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, ...]``` - any idea why?

Comment: If I change the code in ``` mutate(group = rep(1:nrow(df_short), each = 4)) |>``` to 12 instead of 4, since I have 12 columns, I get a dataframe as output but only with ```<chr [1]>``` and ```<NULL>``` as values...

Comment: Could you share the first few rows of `df_short`, e.g. use `dput(df_short)` and paste the output.

Comment: The warnings are okay. These are just where some cells do not contain two pieces of information.

Comment: Sure @Carl, I just posted dput(df_short) of the first 6 rows, does that help?

Comment: Thanks @Soph2010. Is "Bonuses:" intended to be another column? Anyway, I see Wencheng Lau-Medrano has posted something for the second dataset, so see how you get on with that.

Comment: Thank you @Carl, "Bonuses:" was indeed intended to be another column but it should work with the code from Wencheng Lau-Medrano if I just add another column for that